# How to make hbase UI display regionserver as hostname instead of ip?

Tags: hbase

When I upgrade hbase form 0.98.20 to 1.3.0, the regionserver name in hbase web UI is displaying ip instead of hostname. How to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Did you define the mapping in /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Finally, I found that our dns reversing not working.